# Questions about the definition of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set is actually a collection of well defined and distinct objects or numbers.
What does well defined mean here?

An empty set is one with no elements.Note that set is a collection, it should have something in it, so why is an empty set called a set?

A set should have its elements written in small letters(a rule for sets). How would you express the set of capital letters of English alphabets in tabular form if one asks you?

Comment: The fact that an empty set is also a set is  'vacuously true'.

Comment: You can use capital letters to denote set elements if you like. Are you afraid to anger the math gods?

Comment: Why should the elements of a set be written in lowercase? I've never heard that rule before . . .

Comment: You don't necessarily define what a set is. You just say that you are allowed to use the relation $\in$ to compare two sets (i.e. you're allowed to ask whether $x\in y$ is true), and then you have a collection of axioms describing how this relation works, and some specific sets that exists. At least that's the modern approach of ZF set theory.

Comment: Why the downvotes with no comments on a beginner's question that deserves (and has received) nice answers?

Answer (score 5):

**What does it mean that the objects in a set must be well defined?**

If I were to have a set which contains "*the greatest book ever written*" (*the actual book, not the phrase*) and I show this set to other people and ask them if my set is equal to $\{\text{Don Quixote}\}$, some people would say yes and other people would say no.  If I showed it to some people and asked if my set was equal to $\{\text{Moby Dick}\}$, again some would say yes and others would say no.  But... we know that $\{\text{Don Quixote}\}\neq \{\text{Moby Dick}\}$, those are two different books, so which one of these is the book "*the greatest book ever written*"?  (*personally, I'd go with Alice's Adventures*)

In this sense, "*the greatest book ever written*" as an element in a set is not "*well defined*" because it is ambiguous what it means.  We want our objects in sets to mean one and exactly one thing to the person reading and the same thing to any other person reading what we write so that we may clearly ask questions about whether or not things are equal or what properties our set and elements in our set has.  We want to avoid possible misinterpretations.

---

**Why is the empty set a set?**

A collection may have zero things in it, one thing in it, two things in it,... on up to infinitely many things in it (*for whatever type of infinite suits me at the time*).  All that is required is that all things (**if any happen to exist**) in the set are well defined and distinct.  Just because the English use of the word "collection" usually implies that it is non-empty, in mathematics we do not keep that requirement.

---

**Do elements in the set need to be lower case letters?**

No, absolutely not.  It is by *convention* that if we refer to an arbitrary set that we *often* will choose to use capital letters and will *often* refer to arbitrary elements of sets using lower case letters, however that is not a rule.  It is a guideline which we intentionally ignore whenever it suits our purposes.  We only do that so that someone reading our work *at a glance* can have a guess as to what each symbol means, however if it makes our writing clearer, we may use other letters, symbols, pictures, hieroglyphics, kanji, or any other manner we so choose to denote sets, objects, elements, variables, functions, or whatever we need.

If you want to call your set $\heartsuit$, go right ahead.  If you want to let the objects in your sets be $\unknowncharacter$, go right ahead.  The point is to be clear with what you are writing so that anyone reading it will know exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: Very good answer sir

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the facts. Well defined means the members in the set must be clearly defined. For example do you said that the "set of good students in a class" is a set?

The answer is no. Because the one who looks as a good student for you need not a good student for me in my view.but the set of all students in a class is well defined but not the set of all good students.

The empty set refers that it is a set which has no elements. Note that absolutely nothing is different from an empty box containing nothing.I.e a set containing no elements.A set can be seen as a container containing some elements.If there is nothing in a container you can't say that it is not a container.so the set containing no elements is a set.

Small alphabets are used to DENOTE  the members of a set(it is just a convention you need not to follow). It is not said that the set can contain only small letters.
You can write the set of capital letters as $\alpha$={A,B,C,...,Z}.

Comment: I would discourage writing the set of capital letters as $A=\{A,B,C,\dots,Z\}$ as it is unclear if the set $A$ is different than the element $A$, you will have reused symbols (*something we try to avoid whenever possible*).  Suggest instead writing as $\text{CapitalLetters}=\{A,B,C,\dots,Z\}$

Comment: +1 @JMoravitz 's nearly simultaneous answer is similar and better, but his reputation suggests he has a lot more experience than you at explaining mathematics.

Comment: Is it OK now? @jmoravitz

Comment: @NamasivayamKalithasan Of course.  The point I was making was that symbols should avoid being reused and one of the unfortunate things about sets is that a set cannot be an element of itself.  With the notation initially used, that could have been one of the interpretations.  If I ever have to refer to a projection, a permutation, and a circle constant in the same document, although I prefer to denote them all as $\pi$, I would use other symbols for some to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'well-defined' just means that whatever expression you give for identifying which objects are in the set, versus which objects are not in the set, is clear, completely evaluable, and unambiguous.  For example, if I give this definition:

```
E = { x : x is an even integer }
```

then this set is well-defined, because we clearly know what are the integers and which of them are even.  Contrast this with the following:

```
S = { x : x is an interesting integer }
```

then this set IS NOT well-defined, because we have no clear, universally-accepted notion of what makes an integer 'interesting'.

Here's another, slightly different pair.  Let us assume we are in a room with a bunch of people (e.g more than one hundred), and we mark a period of time when no one enters or leaves the room.  Then this set is well-defined:

```
P = { p : p is a person in that room during that period, who is over 5 feet in height }
```

This set is well-defined because we have pinned down the room and the period, and exact height measurement is feasible *(assume there are no cases too close to call)*.  Contrast with this:

```
P = { p : p is a person in that room during that period, who is short }
```

This set IS NOT well-defined, because 'short' is a 'fuzzy' criterion.